# JQuery clone incrementing id was not coming sequence and for deleting the row also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

currently working jQuery clone where I am increment id for the entire div with my current code Increment was working but not in sequence  expy -1 and if user click add more button it generating random id number expy-3. So once when I add the row I want to delete the row with my code i can able to delete the row but the id was not decrementing for example if i have expy-1, expy-2 expy-3 if i delete expy-2 the expy-3 id has to change expy-2 because already i had expy1

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).on("click", ".exp_add_button", function() {
var $clone = $('.cloned-row3:eq(0)').clone(true, true);
var num = $('.cloned-row3').length;
$clone.find(".chk_Field_exp").val('');
  $clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
    this.id += '_' + num;
    $(this).removeClass("errRed");
    if ($(this).hasClass("required_Field")) {
      $(this).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').removeClass('text-error-red');
      $(this).addClass("cloned_field");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("errRed");
      $(this).removeClass("text-error-red");
    }
  });
$clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 edu_btnle' id='buttonless" + (++rowCount) + "'/>")
$clone.attr('id', "expy-" + (++rowCount)).addClass('exp_add');
$clone.find(".startDate").val('');  
$clone.find(".endDate").val('');
/*$clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');*/
$clone.find(".startDate,.endDate")
  .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
  .removeData('datepicker')
  .datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    showButtonPanel: false,

    beforeShow: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

      }, 0);
    }
  });

$(this).parents('.wrk_exp').after($clone);
});
```

Here is the code for delete

```
  $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
var len = $('.cloned-row3').length;
if (len > 1) {
  $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
}
```

});

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/afzde7ku/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need IDs here? I guess no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are increasing the value of `rowCount` twice, in these two line:

```
$clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 edu_btnle' id='buttonless" + (++rowCount) + "'/>")
$clone.attr('id', "expy-" + (++rowCount)).addClass('exp_add');
```

Remove one `++` from the bottom `rowCount`, code will be:

```
$clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 edu_btnle' id='buttonless" + (++rowCount) + "'/>")
$clone.attr('id', "expy-" + (rowCount)).addClass('exp_add');
```

[***Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/afzde7ku/1/)

`++rowCount` changes the value of `rowCount` and is equal to

```
rowCount = rowCount+1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i have one more question for example if i add 5 row and 1,2,3,4,5 if i am deleting the row 3 currently it was coming as 1,2,4,5 but it should come as 1,2,3,4 kindly please help me for that

Comment: This answers part of the question. When you remove the id does not decrement.

Comment: @KФ I am not getting that could you please explain me more :(

Comment: @void kindly please explain me why if i click add  more button it was adding perfectly but for example if i click add more initalli y my value was add1, add2 but if i click the button  from add1 the add3 was generating inisde add1 & add2 not after add2 :(

Comment: @void if you have time kindly look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393347/jquery-clone-sequence-was-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @Mahadevan sure thing.

Comment: @Mahadevan check the answer.