# JQuery clone sequence was not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the continuation with previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392379/jquery-clone-incrementing-id-was-not-coming-sequence-and-for-deleting-the-row-al) question with this current code where I can able to see consecutive number If i did like this initially my id starts with expy -1, if i click add more button it was coming perfectly expy-2 but when i click from expy -1 the expy-3 clone has to come after expy-2 not inside expy-1 and expy-2

And when I try to delete expy-2 from there it has to automatically detect the id
for example if i have expy-1,expy-2,expy-3 & expy-4 if i delete expy2 the final result should come as expy-1,expy-2,expy-3

As per the Previous user told i have removed `++rowCount` and changed to `rowcount`

```
$clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
     this.id += '_' + num;
     console.log(this.id);
     $(this).removeClass("errRed");
     if ($(this).hasClass("required_Field")) {
       $(this).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').removeClass('text-error-red');
       $(this).addClass("cloned_field");
     } else {
       $(this).removeClass("errRed");
       $(this).removeClass("text-error-red");
     }
   });
   $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 edu_btnle' id='buttonless" + (++rowCount) + "'/>")
   $clone.attr('id', "expy-" + (rowCount)).addClass('exp_add');
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/afzde7ku/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `click` of `btn_less1` allot `colned-row3` new `ids`

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
   var len = $('.cloned-row3').length;
   if (len > 1) {
     $(this).closest(".btn_less1").closest(".cloned-row3").remove();
   }

   // Iterating cloned-row3 and changin the id
   $(".cloned-row3").each(function(i){
        this.id = "expy-"+(i+1);
   });
 });
```

[***Live Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/afzde7ku/2/)

Makes sense?

Comment: one more issue was pending with this if i click add more button for the first time expy-1 is coming and expy-2 is coming but if i click again expy-1 the expy-3 (row) was generating inside expy-1 and expy-2 not after expy-2 can you kindly please look this

Comment: @Mahadevan i couldn't understand please explain.

Comment: ok for example if i click first time add more  button my next row id was  generating expy-2 2) if i click the add more button from the beginning the expy-3 was generated it has to come after expy-2 but currently the sequence was wrong it was coming inside

Comment: Okay here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/afzde7ku/3/ , all i have done is i am sequencing the ids on the genration of new clone as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks buddy this was working good can you please up vote my question :)